# Flutter to ios device error: pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. How to fix?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, bundle-identifier

Apologies in advance, I'm a newbie.
I have an app that runs on my iPhone emulator, but when I plugged in a real iPhone I got some errors.

"Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): No profiles for 'com.example.dynoTestMay0123' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.example.dynoTestMay0123'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild."
"Verify that the Bundle Identifier in your project is your signing id in Xcode
open ios/Runner.xcworkspace"

I have only worked in Flutter/Dart, and no nothing about the Xcode environment or swift language. Can someone please explain to me what this error message is asking of me? I am unsure how to handle this.

To solve this, should I be in Xcode? On the phone itself? Or can this be solved in Flutter?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Moral of the story is Apple is kind of annoying (very annoying). You (as a developer) are allowed to develop on emulators all you want (to a point, cant build ipa files). However to run on a physical device you need to have a paid apple developer account, and the associate provisioning profiles and signing certificates.

So you did nothing wrong on your part, just apples' really bad way of telling you that you need a developer account to run on physical devices.

I can assist with the apple developer account portion if needed.

Comment: Ah okay! Yes, I would love assistance in getting a developer account. Or at least get me going in the right direction

Comment: Step 1: https://developer.apple.com/ go here and create an apple developer account, however there is a yearly fee (in USD it is $100). It takes a day or 2 for them to approve the acccount.

Step 2: Once approved login into https://appstoreconnect.apple.com , this is where you would manage your applications. where as developer.apple you would manage your profiles and certifcates.